# Asking Gradle to skip a module in multi-module build

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-module build where one module is temporarily not building, but where I still want to publish the snapshot artifacts for the other modules from our CI servers.  Is there a way to tell Gradle to skip a module from the command line?  Like -x for tasks, but for an entire module?

Or any other way that does not involve editing the build file(s) or settings.gradle?

Comment: Have you tried `-a` switch? Is that what you're looking for: http://java.dzone.com/articles/gradle-goodness-skip-building ?

Comment: -a is not relevant here.  -a deals with project dependencies, not sub-project inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at gradle command line options there doesn't seems to be a way to skip specific sub-project(s).
However, you can use the -p flag to instruct gradle to BUILD a specific sub-project which will also make gradle build all the sub-project the provided project is dependent on.
Therefore, if you have a sub-project depending on all other modules except that one that you do not want to build then you just need to use the -p flag with this sub-project. If this is not the case then as a simple workaround you can defined a dummy sub-project that will be dependent only on the project you'd like to build (the last option means changing settings.gradle files, but this is probably a one time change).